# Как создать запрос в elasticsearch, используя java api (SearchResponce) с аггрегацией?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Как создать запрос в elasticsearch, используя java api (SearchResponce) с аггрегацией? Например простой запрос в Elastic на порт 9200, будет такой:

```
{
    "_source":"username",
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
            "users":{
                "terms":{
                    "field":"username.keyword",
                    "order": {
                        "sum":"desc"
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "sum": {
                        "sum": {
                            "field":"fileSize"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
    "total": {
        "cardinality": {
            "field":"username.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

кажется так, получилось самому разобраться:

```
SearcheResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch(index)
       .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
       .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("users").field("username.keyword")
       .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum").field("fileSize")))
       .get();
```